# C# CryptoStream result not as expected

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptostream

I'm trying to understand why the following code results in the encrypted byte array being 16 bytes if `plainText` is 8 bytes in length. I expected the result to also be 8 bytes in length?

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] plainText)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = key, IV = key };

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                {
                    bw.Write(plainText);
                }
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered in: [DES encryption of 8 bytes plain text results in 16 bytes array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262594/des-encryption-output)

Comment: BTW... I wrote a little app to help me test different encryption algs some time ago... I've posted the source code on QDrive at https://www.qdrive.net/download/sharelinkdownloader.php?id=45392&key=zxF92nDxOmF3Iq86OpB98X8xzmX3MjD6zpN . It's a bit rough, but it works... not highly functional but might have something of use.